# how to include photo and format section headings

Tags: sectioning

I would like to include an image on the top right of the document (above the horizontal line). Also, I would like to format the section headings (which appear on the left margin of the document) to red color.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1em} %1em}
\newlength{\bibsep}
 {\@listi \global\bibsep\itemsep \global\advance\bibsep by\parsep}
\newenvironment{bibsection}%
        {\begin{enumerate}{}{%
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
       \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
       \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}%
       \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{enumerate}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}
\makeatother

\reversemarginpar

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
            %includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
            marginparwidth=1.2in,     % Length of section titles
            marginparsep=.05in,       % Space between titles and text
            margin=1in,               % 1 inch margins
            includemp]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newlength{\footpageshift}
\setlength{\footpageshift}
          {0.5\textwidth+0.5\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth-2in}
\lfoot{\hspace{\footpageshift}%
       \parbox{4in}{\, \hfill %
                    \arabic{page} of \protect\pageref*{LastPage} % +LP
                    \hfill \,}}

\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}



 \newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
             {\large \bfseries #2 \hfill #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
    \hyphenpenalty=10000%
    \vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright #1}}}%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}

\newenvironment{outerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*]}{\end{itemize}%
         \vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

\newenvironment{lonelist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{list}{#1}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{list}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

\newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}
        {\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{loneinnerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}
        {\end{itemize}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[3]}
\newcommand{\halfblankline}{\quad\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}\pagebreak[3]}

\newcommand\doilink[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\newcommand\doi[1]{doi:\doilink{#1}}

\providecommand*\url[1]{\href{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand*\url[1]{\href{#1}{\texttt{#1}}}

\providecommand*\email[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

\providecommand\BibTeX{{B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    \TeX}}
\providecommand\Matlab{\textsc{Matlab}}

\begin{document}
 \makeheading{Abhimanyu Arora}

\section{Contact Information}

\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{2in}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength}p{\rcollength}}
Off no. 123  & 123 456 789  \\
Belgium     & \email{abhi@yahoo.com}\\
\end{tabular}


\section{Research Interests}

Development Economics, Microeconomics

\section{Education}

\textbf{University of Belgium},
\begin{outerlist}

\item[] Ph.D. Student, {Economics}
        \begin{innerlist}
        \item Thesis Topic: \emph{Essays in Development Economics}
        \end{innerlist}
\end{outerlist}

\end{document}
```

---

I tried the command

```
\makeheading[\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{my_picutre}]{Your Name}
```

where I just have `\makeheading`, but it didn't work out. The error message says it couldn't find out the end of the line...

Comment: Please make a complete minimal working example.

Comment: This looks like an awful hack of some other class or `.sty` file. I am unsure how to use it and at first glance it does not seem fit to deliver commands for a CV. May I suggest to use `moderncv` instead?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks for your suggestion, but since Werner has advised to use article for its flexibility, let us try this, if you don't mind

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: Well, I agree with Werner about that `letter` issue of yours, but there are definitely differences between a CV and a letter. I would not write a book with `article` (or its corresponding relatives as `scrartcl` etc.) and I would refrain from writing a letter with `book` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without discussing the template you can achieve your goals with:

1. Adding a photo: `\makeheading[{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{photo}}]{Abhimanyu Arora}`
2. Change the style of section:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
       \hyphenpenalty=10000%
       \vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
       \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
       \noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\textcolor{red}{#1}}}}%
       \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}
   ```

---

Here the complete MWE with the result:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1em} %1em}
\newlength{\bibsep}
 {\@listi \global\bibsep\itemsep \global\advance\bibsep by\parsep}
\newenvironment{bibsection}%
        {\begin{enumerate}{}{%
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
       \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
       \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}%
       \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{enumerate}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}
\makeatother

\reversemarginpar

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
            %includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
            marginparwidth=1.2in,     % Length of section titles
            marginparsep=.05in,       % Space between titles and text
            margin=1in,               % 1 inch margins
            includemp]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newlength{\footpageshift}
\setlength{\footpageshift}
          {0.5\textwidth+0.5\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth-2in}
\lfoot{\hspace{\footpageshift}%
       \parbox{4in}{\, \hfill %
                    \arabic{page} of \protect\pageref*{LastPage} % +LP
                    \hfill \,}}

\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}



 \newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
             {\large \bfseries #2 \hfill #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
    \hyphenpenalty=10000%
    \vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\textcolor{red}{#1}}}}%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}

\newenvironment{outerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*]}{\end{itemize}%
         \vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

\newenvironment{lonelist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{list}{#1}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{list}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

\newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}
        {\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{loneinnerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}
        {\end{itemize}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[3]}
\newcommand{\halfblankline}{\quad\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}\pagebreak[3]}

\newcommand\doilink[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\newcommand\doi[1]{doi:\doilink{#1}}

\providecommand*\url[1]{\href{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand*\url[1]{\href{#1}{\texttt{#1}}}

\providecommand*\email[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

\providecommand\BibTeX{{B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    \TeX}}
\providecommand\Matlab{\textsc{Matlab}}

\begin{document}
\makeheading[{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{photo}}]{Abhimanyu Arora}


\section{Contact Information}

\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{2in}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength}p{\rcollength}}
Off no. 123  & 123 456 789  \\
Belgium     & \email{abhi@yahoo.com}\\
\end{tabular}


\section{Research Interests}

Development Economics, Microeconomics

\section{Education}

\textbf{University of Belgium},
\begin{outerlist}

\item[] Ph.D. Student, {Economics}
        \begin{innerlist}
        \item Thesis Topic: \emph{Essays in Development Economics}
        \end{innerlist}
\end{outerlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Grazie. But how can I change the size of the image, please? It shows error when I use square brackets to specify width as in normal `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: As usual by the optional argument of `\includegraphics`: `\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{photo}`

Comment: You have to use `{\includegraphics[....]{photo}}` to protect the inner optional `[]` from the outer ones

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: The the comment of Christian. I improved my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks to both. But now the image is on the top left. How to make it flush right---with name on the top left?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: I also found Marco's solution, with a different scaling however, but he was quicker (;-)), and the picture is on the right side.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: lol :D. Where is your answer?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: In my editor ;-) -- there is no need to post an almost equal answer, so the credits should go to Marco. As a proof, see below :D

Comment: Very strange, I ger picture on left hand side with my name jumbled up over and under the horizontal line

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: In your edit of the original post your forgot the extra braces: `\makeheading[{\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{my_picutre}}]{Your Name}`